# Replace by a list in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to replace a list of the word **flipInY** with a different word for each occurrence. For example, I have this:

```
flipInY flipInY flipInY flipInY flipInY flipInY flipInY flipInY flipInY flipInY
```

I want it to become this:

```
bounce flash pulse rubberBand shake headShake swing tada wobble jello
```

Is there a way to do this automatically with Sublime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a series of built-in shortcuts.

1. Type your list into the editor, with each item on its own line:

   ```
   bounce
   flash
   pulse
   rubberBand
   shake
   headShake
   swing
   tada
   wobble
   jello
   ```
2. Select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> / <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).
3. Split selection into lines (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> / <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>). This creates a cursor on each line. In your case, you should have 10 cursors.
4. Copy.
5. In the file with all the `flipInY`s, find and select every instance. You can do this by opening the find panel, typing in `flipInY`, and clicking *Find All* (or alt+enter). Note that this won't work unless you have the same number of occurrences of `flipInY`. In your case, there should be 10.
6. Paste.